# html5 video player size on safari browsers

Tags: html, safari, html5-video

I've got a problem on Safari browser (PC/MAC) with a HTML5 `video` player element.

The problem is that the played video does not reflect the real video of the video `source` elements, neither does the size specified with the `width` and `height` attributes.

Here is the demo URL:

http://actisku.videohosting.fr/test.html

```
<video id="homepage_videoplayer" poster="http://actisku.videohosting.fr/medias/videos/v_actisku_visualproject_sephora_61.png" loop="loop"  autoplay="autoplay" width="979" height="365">
     <source src="http://actisku.videohosting.fr/medias/videos/v_actisku_visualproject_sephora_61.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
     <source src="http://actisku.videohosting.fr/medias/videos/v_actisku_visualproject_sephora_61.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
</video>
```

The `mp4` source file is 979x365. So is the player `video` element which is also specified at that same size. But it should be read at the same size.

Maybe it's a metadata problem, but I don't know how to edit this metadata.

EDIT:

With JavaScript , I can see the video `width` is 649 on Safari and 979 on Chrome, pretty strange. So I'm planning to use `-webkit-transform` `scaleX()` to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a javascript error on line: 39

```
vid.css("video","scaleX(1.5)");
```

I think that what you are trying to do is to add the attribute

```
scaleX="1.5"
```

to the `<video>` tag, is that so?  Try adding it manually to see if that's what you are looking for, so you would end up with this:

```
<video id="homepage_videoplayer" scaleX="1.5" poster="http://actisku.videohosting.fr/medias/videos/v_actisku_visualproject_sephora_61.png" loop="loop"  autoplay="autoplay" width="979" height="365">
    <source src="http://actisku.videohosting.fr/medias/videos/v_actisku_visualproject_sephora_61.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://actisku.videohosting.fr/medias/videos/v_actisku_visualproject_sephora_61.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />    
</video>
```

Comment: the problem is that scaleX must only apply on safari, on other browser I dont get any issue.

Comment: Do you just want to "make-it-fit"?  If so, check out this idea http://jsfiddle.net/MDppT/  I tested it in Safari and Chrome and it scales to fit the size of the `DIV`

Comment: davehale23, I tried that and it works in safari but not in webviews in iOS.